# SwiftUI Picker and Buttons inside same Form section are triggered by the same user click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this `AddWorkoutView` and I am trying to build some forms similar to what Apple did with "Add new contact" sheet form.
Right now I am trying to add a form more complex than a simple `TextField` (something similar to "add address" from Apple contacts but I am facing the following issues:

- in the Exercises section when pressing on a new created entry (exercise), both `Picker` and delete `Button` are triggered at the same time and the `Picker` gets automatically closed as soon as it gets open and the selected entry is also deleted when going back to `AddWorkoutView`.

Does anyone have any idea on how Apple implemented this kind of complex form like in the screenshow below?

Thanks to RogerTheShrubber response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633875/how-to-dynamically-add-text-fields-like-contacts-with-swiftui) I managed to somehow implement at least the add button and to dynamically display all the content I previously added, but I don't know to bring together multiple TextFields/Pickers/any other stuff in the same form.

[image: Check here about what kind of form I am talking about]

```
struct AddWorkoutView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    @EnvironmentObject var dateModel: DateModel
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var workout: Workout = Workout()
    @State var exercises: [Exercise] = [Exercise]()
    
    func getBinding(forIndex index: Int) -> Binding<Exercise> {
        return Binding<Exercise>(get: { workout.exercises[index]      },
                                 set: { workout.exercises[index] = $0 })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section("Workout") {
                    TextField("Title", text: $workout.title)
                    TextField("Description", text: $workout.description)
                }
                
                Section("Exercises") {
                    ForEach(0..<workout.exercises.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: { workout.exercises.remove(at: index) }) {
                                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                            }
                            Divider()
                            VStack {
                                TextField("Title", text: $workout.exercises[index].title)
                                Divider()
                                Picker(selection: getBinding(forIndex: index).type, label: Text("Type")) {
                                    ForEach(ExerciseType.allCases, id: \.self) { value in
                                        Text(value.rawValue)
                                            .tag(value)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        workout.exercises.append(Exercise())
                    } label: {
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(.trailing)
                            Text("add exercise")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create new Workout")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Cancel")
                    }
                    .accessibilityLabel("Cancel adding Workout")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Done")
                    }
                    .accessibilityLabel("Confirm adding the new Workout")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You put everything in one row, so it is handled as one (!) row... Form is not for that, place every active control into separated row.

Comment: From what I see : picker of all exercises have same id : that means one picker to rule them all. Put your exercise row in a new View struct ti make each exercise independent.

Comment: @Asperi, I really don't know how split the `TextField` and `Picker` of Exercises section in multiple rows. I want the red minus sign to be somehow centered to all the properties of Exercise data type from the right (Title, Type in this example). Do you have any idea? Thanks!